# NetworkX: How to build a k-Partite Graph graph

Tags: python, networkx

I have a set of *m* nodes, let's name them *N0, N1, N2, ..., Nm*. Using `networkx` I would like to build a graph like the one on the picture below, i.e., a graph in which the nodes are arranged into *k* layers, each layer has *l* nodes (each node belongs to exactly 1 layer). Each node from layer *i* is connected with each node in layer *i+1* (where *0 <= i <= to k-1*).

So, for example, if we have 6 nodes: *N0, N1, N2, N3, N4, N5* and the graph should have k=3, l=2 then the connectivity would look as *N0* is connected to *N2, N3; N1* is connected to *N2, N3; N2* is connected to *N4, N5; N3* is connected to *N4, N5*;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach might be the following.

```
N_LAYERS = 5
N_NODES = 3

g = nx.Graph()

for layer in range(N_LAYERS - 1):
    for u in range(N_NODES):
        for v in range(N_NODES):
            g.add_edge((u,layer),(v,layer+1))
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following should do your job:

```
def create_k_partite_graph(layers, node_per_layer):
    g = nx.Graph()
    previous_layer_nodes = []
    actual_layer_nodes = []
    current_node_id = 0
    for k in range(layers):
        for node in range(node_per_layer):
            g.add_node(current_node_id)
            actual_layer_nodes.append(current_node_id)
        
            for previous_node in previous_layer_nodes:
                g.add_edge(current_node_id, previous_node)
                
            current_node_id +=1
        
        previous_layer_nodes = actual_layer_nodes
        actual_layer_nodes = []
    
    return g
```